# Windows | LxssManager is missing from services.msc

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to download Ubuntu on my windows machine via WSL, and facing difficulties.

I need to turn on Windows Subsystem for Linux in windows features. After I do that and restart the machine, it switches back off.

Now, people recommend to restart the LxssManager.dll service, which looks like it will actually solve the issue. The problem is my machine is missgine the LxssManager service...

The QUESTION:

Does anyone know where I might be able to download it again safely? Or where is it located within the machine (by default)? so I could add it manually via powershell (given it is there of course)

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: What version of Windows Server are you running exactly?  Have you verified that Windows Subsystem for Linux is actually installed?

Answer (score 0):

The LxssManager server really *is* Windows Subsystem for Linux (or at least a major part of it), so if the feature is getting disabled on reboot, that's also why the service is missing.  So no, restarting the service isn't going to fix this.

What we really need to do is to solve your root issue of WSL being disabled after restart.

Your problem sounds very similar to these two Github issues:

- [Can't install the windows feature](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/931#issuecomment-265791282)
- [Can't install WSL - feature unchecked after each restart](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1304)

In multiple cases, the solution has been to:

- Start an Admin PowerShell
- `rmdir "$env:windir\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Subsystem For Linux"
- Restart the PC
- Reenable Windows Subsystem for Linux.  This can also be done from the commandline by starting an Admin PowerShell and:

  ```
  Dism /online /Get-FeatureInfo /FeatureName:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
  ```
- Reboot
- Pay close attention during the reboot.  If there are any errors, please note them in an edit to the question.

But hopefully, there will be no errors or warnings and the feature will be enabled properly after that.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This didn't solve the issue for me. Apparently I had a couple of missing and corrupted files which interrupted the process. 

I ended up doing a windows reboot as I screwed up a few other things on the way haha, but now it seems to be working great! 

Thank tho!